# Format index items differently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a fairly common index view but I would like to format the first item differently than others. How do I differentiate the first item from the rest to acheive something like using `<h1>` tags for the first link instead of `<h5>`?

```
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <% if link.points == 0 then @points = "?" else @points = link.points%>
  <% end %>
    <p>
      <h5> 
        <%= link_to '+', up_link_url(link), :method => :put, :class => "label success" %> 
        <%= @points %> 
        <%= link_to '-', down_link_url(link), :method => :put, :class => "label important" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <%= link_to strip_tags(link.title), link %>
      </h5>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
<% @links.each_with_index do |link, index| %>
  <% if link.points == 0 then @points = "?" else @points = link.points%>
  <% end %>
    <p>
      <% if index == 0 then %> <h1> <% else %> <h5> <% end %>
        <%= link_to '+', up_link_url(link), :method => :put, :class => "label success" %>
        <%= @points %>
        <%= link_to '-', down_link_url(link), :method => :put, :class => "label important" %> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <%= link_to strip_tags(link.title), link %>
      <% if index == 0 then %> </h1> <% else %> </h5> <% end %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of options, but I'd have a link partial to start with, and keep most of this out of the mainline template.

You could use `each_with_index` and either have the partial decide which header tag to use, or link indices to the header level (like with a map, but probably overkill).

Or you could render the first item (`@links.first`) manually (again with a partial, passing in the header tag string) and do the remaining items via a loop. I actually tend towards this one, since it keeps the mainline template pretty clean, but very communicative, and you don't have to dig into the template to see why things are rendering differently.

On an unrelated note, from a semantic viewpoint, jumping from `h1` to `h5` with no intervening headers is a bit weird.